# DirectX 11: How to outline a bounding box?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, directx, directx-11

In a 2d platform game, I want to visualize the bounding box that I have created to aid debugging. How can I accomplish this in Visual C++ 2012?

Comment: DirectX 9, 10, or 11?

Comment: In DirectX 9, there's a [`ID3DXLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface that may interest you.

Comment: In DirectX 11 I think

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) What exactly the problem? You cannot draw a rectangle? Or you need to figure out a bounding box itself?

Comment: I can draw the boundingBox. What I wanted was to have the bounding box edges be visible so it could help me when debugging.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you'd add an explanation of how you drawing it now. Do you able to draw opaque rectangle in place of bounding volume, but would like to draw just edges? I get it right?

Comment: I use: Windows::Foundation::Rect getBoundingBox(Windows::Foundation::Rect boundingBox);   Rect Diamonds::getBoundingBox(Rect boundingBox)
{
 this->boundingBox.Width = boundingBox.Width;
 this->boundingBox.Height = boundingBox.Height;
 return this->boundingBox;
} The boundingBox is currently invisible, what I want is to actually be able to see the boundingBox, e.g. colour in the edges.

Answer (score 4):

First define a simple vertex structure:

```
struct Vertex
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 position; //a 3D point even in 2D rendering
};
```

Now you can create vertex and index arrays:

```
Vertex *vertices;
unsigned long *indices = new unsigned long[5];
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc, indexBufferDesc;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexData, indexData;

//create the vertex array
vertices = new Vertex[5];
if(!vertices)
{
    //handle error
}
//load the vertex array with data
vertices[0].position = D3DXVECTOR3(left, top, 0.0f);
vertices[1].position = D3DXVECTOR3(right, top, 0.0f);
vertices[2].position = D3DXVECTOR3(right, bottom, 0.0f);
vertices[3].position = D3DXVECTOR3(left, bottom, 0.0f);
vertices[4].position = D3DXVECTOR3(left, top, 0.0f);
//create the index array
indices = new unsigned long[5];
if(!indices)
{
    //handle error
}
//load the index array with data
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    indices[i] = i;
```

And load them into buffers:

```
ID3D11Buffer *vertexBuffer, *indexBuffer;
HRESULT result;

//set up the description of the dynamic vertex buffer
vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC; //enables recreation and movement of vertices
vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 5;
vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE; //couples with dynamic
vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
vertexBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;
//give the subresource structure a pointer to the vertex data
vertexData.pSysMem = vertices;
vertexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
vertexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

//now create the vertex buffer
result = device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexData, &vertexBuffer);
if(FAILED(result))
{
    //handle error
}

//set up the description of the static index buffer
indexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
indexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(unsigned long) * 5;
indexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
indexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
indexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
indexBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;
//give the subresource structure a pointer to the index data
indexData.pSysMem = indices;
indexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
indexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

//create the index buffer
result = device->CreateBuffer(&indexBufferDesc, &indexData, &indexBuffer);
if(FAILED(result))
{
    //handle error
}
```

Set up the rectangle to be rendered like this:

```
unsigned int stride = sizeof(Vertex);
unsigned int offset = 0;

deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
deviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINESTRIP);
```

Now render with the shader of your choice, remembering to pass the [orthographic matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204940%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the shader instead of the perspective matrix.  Voilà!  Rectangle.  But you can't move it yet... You have to define another function to do that:

```
bool UpdateRectBuffers(ID3D11Buffer *vertexBuffer, ID3D11DeviceContext *deviceContext, float top, float left, float bottom, float right)
{
    Vertex *vertices;
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    VertexType *verticesPtr;
    HRESULT result;

    //create a temporary vertex array to fill with the updated data
    vertices = new Vertex[5];
    if(!vertices)
    {
        return false;
    }
    vertices[0].position = D3DXVECTOR3(left, top, 0.0f);
    vertices[1].position = D3DXVECTOR3(right, top, 0.0f);
    vertices[2].position = D3DXVECTOR3(right, bottom, 0.0f);
    vertices[3].position = D3DXVECTOR3(left, bottom, 0.0f);
    vertices[4].position = D3DXVECTOR3(left, top, 0.0f);

    //lock the vertex buffer so it can be written to
    result = deviceContext->Map(vertexBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    verticesPtr = (Vertex*)mappedResource.pData;

    //copy the data into the vertex buffer
    memcpy(verticesPtr, (void*)vertices, (sizeof(Vertex) * 5));

    deviceContext->Unmap(vertexBuffer, 0);
    delete [] vertices;
    vertices = 0;

    return true;
}
```

The dependencies of this code are `float top`, `float left`, `float right`, `float left`, `ID3D11DeviceContext *deviceContext`, and `ID3D11Device *device`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I am getting red lines.This says it's undefined: {left, top, 0.0},
  {right, top, 0.0},
  {right, bottom, 0.0},
  {left,  bottom, 0.0},
  {left, top, 0.0}... The new keyword here says 'a value of type unsigned long cannot be initialized to an entity of unsinged long'... unsigned long indices = new unsigned long[5]... and more red lines throughout. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have included the D3DXVECTOR3.h file.

Comment: @user2893921 I was thinking back to the days of `DrawPrimitiveUP`.  It's fixed now; see if that works.

Comment: I have red lines under vertexBufferDesc, vertexData, result, indexBufferDesc, indexData. It says they are 'undefined'. Any ideas why? I am sure you're code works and it's a fault on mine because I don't understand the code.

Comment: @user2893821 No, again not your fault.  I threw this together from a lot of different sources and it's pretty easy to tell.  Work now?

Comment: Lots of red lines gone. Only red lines now are: '&stride' and 'result'. They are 'undefined'. I presume this is because the word 'result' doesn't have a data type? Not sure about the &stride one though.

Comment: @user2893921 xD How about now?

Comment: ID3D11VertexBuffer is undefined and red lines under lots of these: verticesPtr = (Vertex*)mappedResource.pData;

    //copy the data into the vertex buffer
    memcpy(verticesPtr, (void*)vertices, (sizeof(Vertex) * 5));

    this->m_d3dDeviceContext->Unmap(vertexBuffer, 0);
    delete [] vertices;
    vertices = 0;

    return true;

Comment: @user2893921 Define "red lines"?

Comment: Red lines: at curly brace under bool UpdateRectBuffers() that says expected ;  , verticesPtr has no storage class or type specifier, (Vertex*) is undefined, mappedResource expected ;   , memcpy no storage class, (verticesPtr, expected a ','   , this->m_d3dContext->Unmap(vertexBuffer, 0) expected a decleration, delete expected a decleration, vertices has no storage type or type specifier, return true } expected decleration

Comment: @user2893921 Place the `Vertex` struct somewhere that all this can access.  I'm not going to provide anymore support, though.  Extended discussions in the comments are discourages, and you haven't reputation enough for me to move this to chat.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>As you did not described well what you are able to do already, my answer is based on some assumptions.</sup>

### Assumptions

So, I'm assuming that

- you are able to draw a [sprite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29) (i.e. a colored/textured rectangle, i.e. quad of vertices / duet of triangles)
- you already have data, that defines bounding volume (in any of several ways)

and will not explain how to do it.

### Possible solutions

- **Variant 1:**
  You don't need anything special to draw edges. "Edges" (straight lines) are just long and thin rectangles. So, you need to put 4 thin rectangles in place where your edges should be.

  This way you can choose thickness, color of line and even use a texture (dotted lines, dashed lines, lines with pink kittens, etc.) or shader effects, like procedural coloring, smoothing, blur, etc. Anyway, you will likely need lines for your game.
- **Variant 2:**
  You can draw lines instead of triangles. Use "line list" primitive topology, instead of "triangle list".  (See: [ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetPrimitiveTopology()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINELIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

  This way you cannot customize things. But this is much easier.
- **Variant 3:**
  Draw rectangle in wireframe mode. Just set up rasterizer state's fill mode. See: [ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC::FillMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [D3D11_FILL_MODE::D3D11_FILL_WIREFRAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

  You'll get edges of triangles, even that ones that are diagonals of rectangle. This way you cannot set up neither thickness, nor color. But this way is really, really simple.
- **Variant 4:**
  Use any 2D drawing library that will do Variant 1 for you. As [D3DX is obsolete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx), it is not recommended to use D3DXLine anymore. You can try [DirectX toolkit](http://directxtk.codeplex.com/) or any library available on web.
  Obviously you'll get additional dependency.

### P.S.

If my initial assumptions were incorrect, then you'll not get an answer here. No men on StackOverflow will explain you such basic things. To correct a situation:

- There are zillion ways to draw a rectangle. Pick any tutorial online (Ex.: [rastertek](http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html), [braynzarsoft](https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-braynzar-soft-directx-11-tutorials)) to get an idea on what's happening in "Possible solutions" part of this answer.
- There are zillion ways to calculate bounding rectangle for each of zillion ways of defining it. Note, that to define a rectangle in 2D space, you need at least 2 points. And to define a 2D point, you need 2 coordinate values. So 4 values per each rectangle. Google or pick a math book for additional info.

Hope it helps!